# cURL Connection Reset - Site doesn't reply by timeout to POST

Tags: php, post, curl

A php script makes several `curl_exec()` to this site on https (port 443). The option: `curl_setopt($ch, curlopt_timeout, 50)` is set. Occasionally, the target does not respond before  the timeout. The script is set to try the POST request again, but always receives on the subsequent attempt:

```
Error 500: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ...
```

This second result is happening because the curl_exec of the first try did not do something.
Is there a cURL configuration that would allow a 'clean' reattempt, so that the 2nd try might be successful? It would be like using a browser's STOP button in curl (??)

Does such a curlopt exist?

Comment: "I know that this is an issue on the receiving side, and probably in the API to the 3rd site" I think you just answered your own question.  This probably isn't a curl problem, so I don't know how we can help.

Comment: I agree: Not cURL. (Never said it was.) Except that I'd like to operate a script that receives a valid response, instead of the 500. This return is about 5% of the runnings. The question is about exploring my options. Is there a cURL option that might accomplish this?